# yii2 gridview filter with custom value

Tags: gridview, filter, yii2

I have displayed the values as follows :

> 1 => "Active", 0 => "Inactive"

1,0 are the db values.

This is my column.

```
[
            'label' => 'Status',
            'attribute' => 'activeStatus',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value'=>function ($data){return $data->activeStatus ? '<span class="label label-success">Active</span>' : '<span class="label label-danger">Inactive</span>';} 
        ],
```

How to enable grid filter with `Active/Inactive`? It can be a dropdownlist or just by typing Active/Inactive.

Comment: I suggest to use a dropDownList().

Comment: My db has int value, I display the values like `1 => "Active", 0 => "Inactive"`, it's not filtering.

Comment: Just add that array with the `'filter' => ...` key and make sure that `activeStatus` attribute is on the `rules()` list in the model used for searching.

Answer (score 1):

**GridView**

```
[
    'label' => 'Status',
    'attribute' => 'activeStatus',
    'format' => 'html',
    'value' => function ($data){
        return $data->activeStatus ? '<span class="label label-success">Active</span>' : '<span class="label label-danger">Inactive</span>';
    },
    'filter' => [1 => 'Active', 0 => 'Inactive'],
],
```

**SearchModel**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['activeStatus'], 'integer'],
        .
        .
        .
    ];
}

// grid filtering conditions
$query->andFilterWhere([
     'activeStatus' => $this->activeStatus,
]);
```

Comment: Values passing correctly in the url. But it doesn't return values :(

Comment: @BeginnerDev Check your searchModel's filter condition and rules.